# Regex for slug in symfont route

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-routing

I'm having trouble creating a Regex to match URL slugs [a-z] ("words" separated by single dashes) like this:

```
wordone-wordtwo-wordtree
```

in route:

```
csa_platform_category:
    path:     /c/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: CSAPlatformBundle:Category:index }
    requirements:
        slug: "^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$"
```

in twig:

```
<a href="{{ path('csa_platform_category', {'slug': cat.slug}) }}">{{ cat.name }}</a>
```

The displayed error is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "slug" for route "csa_platform_category" must match "[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

I'm quite bad with regular expressions, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In PHP, you need to use regex delimiters to define regex, try `"~^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$~"`

Comment: by adding delimiters an auther error displayed: No route found for "GET /category/mutuelle-sante" <br> csa_platform_category:
    path:     /category/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: CSAPlatformBundle:Category:index }
    requirements:
        slug: "~^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$~"

Comment: Ok, then the issue is just not with the regex at all.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are having is saying than your `cat.slug` is empty.

> ("" given)

You should check the data in cat object using `var_dump` or `dump`